# Remove all sub-fields in column-organized datafile that contain "_XX"

Tags: text-processing, sed, bioinformatics

I have this type of file

```
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO
chr1    69511   rs2691305       A       G       .       PASS    AC=70482;AN=83312;AF=0.846001;popmax=eas;faf95_popmax=0.975176;AC_non_v2_XX=28734;AN_non_v2_XX=33774;AF_non_v2_XX=0.850773;nhomalt_non_v2_XX=13253;AC_non_cancer_fin_XX=1080;AN_non_cancer_fin_XX=1090;AF_non_cancer_fin_XX=0.990826;nhomalt_non_cancer_fin_XX=537;AC_non_neuro_nfe=32992;AN_non_neuro_nfe=34106;AF_non_neuro_nfe=0.967337;nhomalt_non_neuro_nfe=16243;AC_non_neuro_afr_XY=5275;AN_non_neuro_afr_XY=8862;AF_non_neuro_afr_XY=0.595238;nhomalt_non_neuro_afr_XY=1908;AC_non_neuro_nfe_XY=13529;AN_non_neuro_nfe_XY=13954;AF_non_neuro_nfe_XY=0.969543;nhomalt_non_neuro_nfe_XY=6668;AC_controls_and_biobanks_eas_XY=1209;AN_controls_and_biobanks_eas_XY=1210;AF_controls_and_biobanks_eas_XY=0.999174;nhomalt_controls_and_biobanks_eas_XY=604;AC_non_neuro_sas_XX=623;AN_non_neuro_sas_XX=646;AF_non_neuro_sas_XX=0.964396;nhomalt_non_neuro_sas_XX=304;AC_non_v2=53211;AN_non_v2=62346;AF_non_v2=0.853479;nhomalt_non_v2=24615;AC_non_topmed_nfe_XX=4123;AN_non_topmed_nfe_XX=4274;AF_non_topmed_nfe_XX=0.96467;nhomalt_non_topmed_nfe_XX=2022;AC_non_v2_mid=132;AN_non_v2_mid=146;AF_non_v2_mid=0.90411;nhomalt_non_v2_mid=63;AC_non_topmed_sas=2561;AN_non_topmed_sas=2620;AF_non_topmed_sas=0.977481;nhomalt_non_topmed_sas=1262;AC_non_cancer_eas_XX=1882;AN_non_cancer_eas_XX=1882;AC_nfe=34637;AN_nfe=35806;AF_nfe=0.967352;nhomalt_nfe=17050;AC_popmax=4423;AN_popmax=4424;AF_popmax=0.999774;nhomalt_popmax=2211;faf95_sas=0.945756;faf99_sas=0.93297;faf95_eas=0.975176;faf99_eas=0.965135;faf95_amr=0.876957;faf99_amr=0.869526;faf95_afr=0.586993;faf99_afr=0.583779;faf95=0.840765;faf99=0.838605;faf95_nfe=0.958818;faf99_nfe=0.955301;age_hist_het_bin_freq=123|146|149|217|287|242|200|187|124|72;age_hist_het_n_smaller=460;age_hist_het_n_larger=24;age_hist_hom_bin_freq=569|655|765|1405|2028|1746|1691|1518|1005|654;age_hist_hom_n_smaller=1206;age_hist_hom_n_larger=215;FS=0;MQ=41.6849;MQRankSum=-3.98;QD=26.0414;ReadPosRankSum=0.51;VarDP=1761397;QUALapprox=45869299;AS_FS=0;AS_MQ=41.6847;AS_MQRankSum=-3.972;AS_pab_max=1;AS_QD=26.0413;AS_ReadPosRankSum=0.51;AS_SOR=0.865485;InbreedingCoeff=0.521183;AS_SB_TABLE=99037,96244|856526,709549;AS_VQSLOD=0.4266;AS_culprit=AS_MQRankSum;NEGATIVE_TRAIN_SITE;allele_type=snv;n_alt_alleles=2;variant_type=multi-snv;segdup;gq_hist_alt_bin_freq=0|0|0|0|39|89|5016|5173|2494|4247|3343|1353|2059|1764|858|1286|1197|599|785|7691;gq_hist_all_bin_freq=0|0|0|0|2833|660|5232|5237|2506|4249|3343|1354|2060|1764|859|1287|1197|599|785|7691;dp_hist_alt_bin_freq=0|0|12706|9449|5594|4053|2707|1532|828|486|262|166|89|45|36|12|6|7|2|3;dp_hist_alt_n_larger=10;dp_hist_all_bin_freq=0|0|13838|11344|6042|4209|2735|1535|828|487|262|166|89|45|36|12|6|7|2|3;dp_hist_all_n_smaller=0;dp_hist_all_n_larger=10;ab_hist_alt_bin_freq=0|0|0|0|193|367|513|688|876|676|772|504|439|263|124|56|25|8|0|0;cadd_raw_score=0.112916;cadd_phred=2.209;revel_score=0.053;splice_ai_max_ds=0.02;splice_ai_consequence=donor_gain;primate_ai_score=0.632586;vep=G|missense_variant|MODERATE|OR4F5|ENSG00000186092|Transcript|ENST00000335137|protein_coding|1/1||ENST00000335137.4:c.421A>G|ENSP00000334393.3:p.Thr141Ala|457|421|141|T/A|Aca/Gca|1||1|SNV||HGNC|HGNC:14825|YES||P1|CCDS30547.1|ENSP00000334393|||||tolerated(0.820)|benign(0.000)|Gene3D:1&Pfam:PF13853&PROSITE_profiles:PS50262&Superfamily:SSF81321&Transmembrane_helices:TMhelix&CDD:cd15226|||||||||,G|missense_variant|MODERATE|OR4F5|ENSG00000186092|Transcript|ENST00000641515|protein_coding|3/3||ENST00000641515.2:c.484A>G|ENSP00000493376.2:p.Thr162Ala|544|484|162|T/A|Aca/Gca|1||1|SNV||HGNC|HGNC:14825|||||ENSP00000493376|||||tolerated(0.850)|benign(0.000)|Transmembrane_helices:TMhelix&CDD:cd15226&PANTHER:PTHR26451&PANTHER:PTHR26451&Pfam:PF13853&PROSITE_profiles:PS50262&Gene3D:1&Superfamily:SSF81321|||||||||,G|missense_variant|MODERATE|OR4F5|79501|Transcript|NM_001005484.1|protein_coding|1/1||NM_001005484.1:c.421A>G|NP_001005484.1:p.Thr141Ala|421|421|141|T/A|Aca/Gca|1||1|SNV||EntrezGene|HGNC:14825|YES||||NP_001005484.1|||||tolerated(0.820)|benign(0.000)||||||||||
```

and all the strings containing `_XX` between semicolons should be removed, so that from

```
AF_controls_and_biobanks_eas_XY=0.999174;nhomalt_controls_and_biobanks_eas_XY=604;AC_non_neuro_sas_XX=623;AN_non_neuro_sas_XX=646;
```

only

```
AF_controls_and_biobanks_eas_XY=0.999174;nhomalt_controls_and_biobanks_eas_XY=604;
```

stays.

I tried to use `sed`, but unsucesfully:

```
s/[^ ]*_XX[^ ]*//ig

sed -e 's/[^ ]*_XX[^ ]*//ig'

sed '/^_XX/s//'
   
sed 's/*XX//' 

sed 's/^[0-9]*_XX|//'

sed 's/;.*_XX//'
```

Any help will be appreciated to save my life.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you specify how your columns are separated (spaces, tabs, combinations of those)? Is it always the 8th column in the file that contains this `;`-separated list of items? Can there be spaces in any of these `;`-separated "sub-fields"?

Comment: Yes, what @AdminBee said. That _looks_ like a VCF file in which case, fields are separated by tabs, and there can be spaces (but not tabs) in the `;`-separated subfields.

Comment: This is gnomad vcf file; it is always 8th column, INFO field; columns are separated with tabs; yes, there can be space in ; separated fields.  Fields to be removed always contain "_XX= " in the middle and are located in ; ;

Comment: So the `XX` can never be the first sub-field of the INFO field? Also, do you also want to remove the corresponding entries from the header (not shown in your question)? Leaving them isn't a problem for the VCF standard, so up to you.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the solution:

```
sed 's/;[^;]*_XX[^;]*//g'
```

You need to look for `_XX` within two `;`s and so, you should let every other character pass.

Comment: That won't work if the sub-field with the _XX is the first sub-field of the INFO field. Try `sed -E 's/(\t|;)[^;]+_XX=[^;]+;?/$1/g'` instead.

Comment: @terdon *that* won't work for overlapping matches

Comment: @rowboat like what? The pattern is anchored by either a tab or a `;` on the left and (I now see) isn't anchored on the right which is a problem, but easily fixed with `sed -E 's/(\t|;)[^;]+_XX=[^;]+(;|\t)/$1/g'`. However, I don't see how you could get overlapping patterns with these data.

Comment: @rowboat the suggestion from my second comment does indeed not work (it's what I get for posting without testing). But the first does for all except the 1st and last sub-field and shouldn't be affected by overlapping matches in any way. Anyway, I posted my own answer, so if you still find issues with it, please leave a comment there so we don't spam poor unxnut :)

Answer (score 4):

Unxnut already gave you [a working solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/656742/22222), but in order for this to work safely in VCF files, you would also want to ensure that you skip the header lines (those that start with `#`) and only apply the change to the INFO field, the 8th tab-separated field of the line. Finally, you may as well make it so that it also works if the `_XX` sub-field is the first sub-field of the INFO field. Putting all this together, you can do:

```
sed -E '/^[^#]/{s/(\t|;)[^;]+_XX=[^;\t]+/\1/g}' file.vcf
```

Comment: @daniele yes, thank you, I was thinking in Perl.

Answer (score 4):

To manipulate text in the 8th field of tab separated data, and only on lines that don't start with `#`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" }
!/^#/ {
    gsub(/;[^;=]*_XX=[^;]*/, "", $8)
    sub(/^[^;=]*_XX=[^;]*(;|$)/, "", $8)
} 1
' file
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), splitting the `INFO` field into subfields, regex-filtering the subkeys, then joining it back together:

```
mlr --tsv put -S '
  m = splitkvx($INFO,"=",";"); 
  for(k,v in m){if(string(k) =~ "_XX$"){m = mapexcept(m,k)}}; 
  $INFO = joinkv(m,"=",";")
' file.vcf
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO
chr1    69511   rs2691305       A       G       .       PASS    AC=70482;AN=83312;AF=0.846001;popmax=eas;faf95_popmax=0.975176;AC_non_neuro_nfe=32992;AN_non_neuro_nfe=34106;AF_non_neuro_nfe=0.967337;nhomalt_non_neuro_nfe=16243;AC_non_neuro_afr_XY=5275;AN_non_neuro_afr_XY=8862;AF_non_neuro_afr_XY=0.595238;nhomalt_non_neuro_afr_XY=1908;AC_non_neuro_nfe_XY=13529;AN_non_neuro_nfe_XY=13954;AF_non_neuro_nfe_XY=0.969543;nhomalt_non_neuro_nfe_XY=6668;AC_controls_and_biobanks_eas_XY=1209;AN_controls_and_biobanks_eas_XY=1210;AF_controls_and_biobanks_eas_XY=0.999174;nhomalt_controls_and_biobanks_eas_XY=604;AC_non_v2=53211;AN_non_v2=62346;AF_non_v2=0.853479;nhomalt_non_v2=24615;AC_non_v2_mid=132;AN_non_v2_mid=146;AF_non_v2_mid=0.90411;nhomalt_non_v2_mid=63;AC_non_topmed_sas=2561;47=AN_non_t
```

or (perhaps more efficient) assemble the keys whose elements are to be excluded into a map, then use `mapdiff` to remove them together:

```
$ mlr --tsv put -S '
  m = splitkvx($INFO,"=",";");
  e = {};
  for(k,v in m){if(string(k) =~ "_XX$"){e[k] = 1}};
  $INFO = joinkv(mapdiff(m,e),"=",";")
' file.vcf
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO
chr1    69511   rs2691305       A       G       .       PASS    AC=70482;AN=83312;AF=0.846001;popmax=eas;faf95_popmax=0.975176;AC_non_neuro_nfe=32992;AN_non_neuro_nfe=34106;AF_non_neuro_nfe=0.967337;nhomalt_non_neuro_nfe=16243;AC_non_neuro_afr_XY=5275;AN_non_neuro_afr_XY=8862;AF_non_neuro_afr_XY=0.595238;nhomalt_non_neuro_afr_XY=1908;AC_non_neuro_nfe_XY=13529;AN_non_neuro_nfe_XY=13954;AF_non_neuro_nfe_XY=0.969543;nhomalt_non_neuro_nfe_XY=6668;AC_controls_and_biobanks_eas_XY=1209;AN_controls_and_biobanks_eas_XY=1210;AF_controls_and_biobanks_eas_XY=0.999174;nhomalt_controls_and_biobanks_eas_XY=604;AC_non_v2=53211;AN_non_v2=62346;AF_non_v2=0.853479;nhomalt_non_v2=24615;AC_non_v2_mid=132;AN_non_v2_mid=146;AF_non_v2_mid=0.90411;nhomalt_non_v2_mid=63;AC_non_topmed_sas=2561;47=AN_non_t
```

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' 'NR>1{
  split($NF, a, ";")
  $NF=""
  for(i=1; i in a; i++)
    if(a[i]!~/_XX=/)
      $NF = $NF ";" a[i]
  sub(/^;/, "", $NF)
}1' data
```

Use the tab as field separator and identifie the last field.

Split this by each `;` and store it in an array.

Scan each element in the array and if this hold an `_XX` then skip this otherwyse use it to rebuild the field.

Comment: Doing for(I in a) can break the order of the subfields while reconstructing $NF. Hence the change to a C-style for loop.